# Attach data to a newly created row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to add new data to newly created rows using jQuery:

```
$("table").append('<tr id="foo"><td>hi</td></tr>');
$("#foo").data("bar",1);
console.log($("#foo").data()); // returns empty object: Object {}
```

Can I use live() or something of the sort?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct.

Possible points of failure are:

- the `$("table")` selector found no matches. *(Perhaps the DOM is not ready.)*
- there are multiple elements on the page with the ID `foo`. *(This is invalid.)*
- The version of jQuery you're using is so old that `.data()` isn't supported. *(Doubtful)*

If you haven't ensured the DOM is ready, a common solution is to use the [`ready()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").append('<tr id="foo"><td>hi</td></tr>');
    $("#foo").data("bar",1);
    console.log($("#foo").data());
});
```

...or as a shortcut, you can pass the callback directly to the jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
    $("table").append('<tr id="foo"><td>hi</td></tr>');
    $("#foo").data("bar",1);
    console.log($("#foo").data());
});
```

Comment: Patrick, thank you for the concise answer. The example I gave was watered down from my actual example (to simplify things) and I found out that my issue was related to how I had my id attribute named. I was using square brackets (common practice when using PHP) and jQuery didn't recognize the ID selector I was using. I found that I can use slashes to escape the square brackets, which allows jQuery to select the row I want. How do I handle the "answer" part since I figured it out on my own?

Comment: @Travis: You can go ahead and add your solution as an answer, and accept it. In the future, it is best if you provide code in the question that you've verified as being a reproduction of the issue. Just something to keep in mind. ;o)

Comment: ...also, keep in mind that `[]` are invalid characters for IDs in HTML4. It will break in some browsers (even with escaping).

Answer (score 0):

I was using square brackets for the ID and jQuery didn't recognize the ID selector I was using. I found that I can use slashes to escape the square brackets, which allows jQuery to select the row I want.